# How to strikethrough Text in android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to strikethrough a `Text` in Android Jetpack Compose. I have checked some documentation but I still don't find something that looks to what I want to achieve.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/text

This is my Text component:

```
Text("$863",fontSize = 24.sp, modifier = Modifier.width(IntrinsicSize.Min), maxLines = 1)
```

**This is what I want to achieve:**

[image]

Can any one please help me or give me any idea?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

**Add style for text**

```
@Composable
fun TextWithLineThroughExample(){
    Text(
        text = "Text with LineThrough",
        style = TextStyle(textDecoration = TextDecoration.LineThrough)
    )
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Tippu this worked for me

Comment: Text composable accepts now a textDecoration argument so we don't need to override the style anymore

Answer (score 7):

I recommend copying the current style with adjusted properties:

```
@Composable
fun textWithLineThroughExample(){
    Text(
        text = "Text with LineThrough",
        style = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(textDecoration = TextDecoration.LineThrough)
    )
}
```

This approach keeps all other existing style properties (for example within a  [`ProvideTextStyle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#ProvideTextStyle(androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle,kotlin.Function0)) block).

Answer (score 3):

Compose now supports TextDecoration directly on your @Composable Text so you don't have to copy/override the style:

```
@Composable
fun TextWithLineThroughExample(){
    Text(
        text = "Text with LineThrough",
        textDecoration = TextDecoration.LineThrough,
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge, // You can set this separate now
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answers point you can use the `textDecoration` argument, but if you already have an style that need to be slightly modified to fit the crossed-out text, then is better to `copy` your style.

```
        Text(
            ...
            style = YourTheme.typography.normalText.copy(
                textDecoration = TextDecoration.LineThrough,
                color = YourTheme.colors.primaryTextColorLight
            )
        )
```

That way is more understandable than the main style is altered. In this case, the crossed-out text is the same as normal text but with the strike-through and with lighter text color.